# Smooth animation on top of regular Android View

Tags: android, animation

I currently have an app with a regular layout of buttons and widgets. On top of this I'd like to draw some animated sparks and particles and whatnot going on in response to events, so I've got it in a `FrameLayout` with another `View` on top to draw the animations. The problem is I can't work out a way of getting smooth movement out of it. I've tried a few options:

- **`SurfaceView`**: because of the way it takes over the screen, you can't see anything behind a `SurfaceView` so the background is fully black.
- **Override `View.onDraw` and call `invalidate()`**: this almost works, but invalidate isn't a very reliable way of getting a redraw to happen soon, so the motion is very jerky.
- **`Animation` framework**: Testing with `TranslateAnimation`, it seems a bit smoother than using `onDraw()`, but animations are designed to run for a specific duration and I want to draw indefinitely.

Anybody know any tricks to make one of these work properly, or something completely different?

Comment: Animations can definitely run forever -- try the XML attribute `android:repeatCount="infinite"`(if you're defining your TranslateAnimation in XML (or `setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE)` in Java).

Comment: Yes, but that will just cause the interpolatedTime to loop from 0 to 1 forever. Just looping the same animation forever isn't what I want.

Comment: I'm using Android 2.1 and read somewhere that some animation is just generally jerky in this version - if anybody has any evidence to back this up then I'd be happy to accept it.